# Add a delay to MultiSourceFrameArrived of Kinect

Tags: c#, wpf, kinect-sdk

I'm working in a project with Kinect, MS SDK 2, C# and WPF controls.

I setup the event handler **MultiSourceFrameArrived** method to read all frame types. According MS documentation, this runs when a frame arrives from the Kinect, and it is approximately at 30 FPS.

I want to restrict this running behavior (delay) in order to reduce the capture, for instance at 5 FPS, 10 FPS.

I try to use Task.Delay(ms) and Thread.Sleep(ms) (as [in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32074055/kinect-frame-arrived-asynchronous) ). Sorry if this question would be stupid, but I couldn't resolve it yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep a Counter `frameCount` and maintain reduced fps by ignoring frames.

```
static void msfr_MultiSourceFrameArrived(object sender, MultiSourceFrameArrivedEventArgs e)
{
    frameCount++;
    if (frameCount % 6 != 0) return;

    //  Do whatever you want cause you are pirate ... :D
}
```

Comment: A simple, but powerful solution, Thanks, Rafaf Tahsin.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to take some time to process the current frame and then request the latest one, you can subscribe unsubscribe to MultiSourceFrameArrived

So, you shoud do something like this

```
    private void msfr_MultiSourceFrameArrived(object sender, MultiSourceFrameArrivedEventArgs e)
    {
        _reader.MultiSourceFrameArrived -= msfr_MultiSourceFrameArrived;

        /***********************Process your frames here**********************/

        _reader.MultiSourceFrameArrived += msfr_MultiSourceFrameArrived;
    }
```